Expo Router useRoute params not passing
i just updated from sdk 51 to sdk52 on my expo react native app.
Before the update i was trying to push in a route with according params like this:
onPress={() => router.push(../routes/workoutDetail?id=${workout.id})}
But now the parameter im trying to access in the workoutDetail is undefined
useEffect(() => { 
    const workoutId = route.params?.id; 
    if (workoutId) {
      fetchWorkoutDetails(workoutId);
    }
  }, [route.params?.id]);

I tried getting the parameters like this aswell:
const params = useLocalSearchParams();
  const { id = } = params;

but nothing works
I would appreciate any help :)

Have you tried passing the parameter like this?


router.push({
    pathname: '../routes/workoutDetail',
    params: {
        id: workout.id
    }
})



Also, using ../routes may not be the best approach for defining the pathname. It’s better to use the global namespace"

Tried it but didnt work aswell
The workoutDetail pages gets pushed on the screen the data just wont load

const { id } = useLocalSearchParams();
try this

i tried it already aswell, nothing seems to work

This problem was solved when I upgraded to Expo v52.0.7 and ran npx expo install --fix again.
I think that the original update did not update @react-navigation/native from ^6.x to ^7.0.0, and this was fixed.
